# IndexError: list index out of range with dict

Tags: list, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I don't understand why the list index is out of range. Because when I splitted the file 'very_short.csv', it broke up into three parts. For example, it broke up airport, 2007, 175702. Airport is text[0], 2007 is text[1], and 175702 is text[2]. So when I call on newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2])), how is it out of range??

This is the error I am getting...

```
>>> import wordData
>>> words = wordData.readWordFile('very_short.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
words = wordData.readWordFile('very_short.csv')
File "/Users/lol/Desktop/lol's Windows/CS/CS1/hw/uni/wordData.py", line 31, in readWordFile
newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range


class YearCount(rit_object):
    __slots__ = ('year', 'count')
    _types    = (int    ,  int  )


def createYearCount(year, count):
    return YearCount(year, count)

def readWordFile(fileName):
    result = {}
    for line in fileName:
        text = line.split(',')
        wordy = text[0]
        print(text)
        if len(text) > 1:
            newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2]))
            if line not in result:
                result[wordy] = [newYearCount]
            else:
                result[wordy].append(newYearCount)
        else:
            return ''
    return result

def main():
    fileName = input('Enter filename: ')
    print(readWordFile(open(fileName)))

main()
```

This is what it is in my very_short.csv file:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
Enter filename: very_short.csv
['airport', ' 2007', ' 175702\n']
['airport', ' 2008', ' 173294\n']
['request', ' 2005', ' 646179\n']
['request', ' 2006', ' 677820\n']
['request', ' 2007', ' 697645\n']
['request', ' 2008', ' 795265\n']
['wandered', ' 2005', ' 83769\n']
['wandered', ' 2006', ' 87688\n']
['wandered', ' 2007', ' 108634\n']
['wandered', ' 2008', ' 171015\n']
{'request': [YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )], 'airport': [YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )], 'wandered': [YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )]}
Enter a word to calculate the count: airport
['v']
0
```

Answer (score 0):

try printing `text` before the string which gives you the error. Most probably, you have an empty line in the end of your file, which splits to a single-valued list.

instead of

```
    newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2]))
```

use

```
if len(text)>1:
    newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2]))
        if line not in result:
            result[word] = [newYearCount]
        else:
            result[word].append(newYearCount)
else:
    return ''
```

Comment: I was able to print the text before the `newYearCount = createYearCount(int(text[1]), int(text[2]))`, then I notice there is a \n at the end of each line. Is that the problem?

Comment: what was the last line you get? probably it is just a '\n', or an invisible return sign.

Comment: The last line that it printed was ['wandered', ' 2008', ' 171015\n']

Comment: Please check the updated code. It still doesn't work.